# How can I automatically enter an autocomplete item in Vim without a popup menu

Tags: vim, neovim

Is it possible to complete a pattern without opening the autocomplete popup?

Ie, given this typescript example, where I am typing props

```js
type Props = {
  children: React.ReactN<cursor>
}
```

I can press `<c-x><c-o>` to open the omnicomplete menu. If the first entry is `ReactNode`, which I know I want, I can then press `<c-y>` to confirm this completion (I do not have `noselect` as a `completopt`, so the first result will be automatically selected), resulting in

```js
type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode<cursor>
}
```

Perfect. But, is there a way to omit the `<c-x><c-o>`? Ie, if I am confident that the first entry that will appear in my autocomplete menu is the one I want is it possible for me to bind `<c-y>` to just go ahead and complete with the would be first entry?

I have tried

```sh
let completeopt=-menu,nomenu
inoremap <expr> <c-y> pumvisible() ? "\<c-y>" : "\<c-x>\<c-o>\<c-n>"
```

This seems to select the menu item, but doesn't actually update the UI. My statusbar reads "-- Omni completion (^O^N^P) match 2 of 115", but the first entry from autocomplete isn't entered at the cursor as it would be had I have entered those keys manually

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `inoremap` line and think through it. You are missing a crucial step. When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> and `pumvisible()` is false, what happens? Vim triggers omnicompletion with the `<C-X><C-O>`. Then, it selects the next (the second, apparently) entry in the popup menu with `<C-N>`. It doesn't do anything else. Vim does not finish completion because you did not tell it to. Your `inoremap` should end with `<C-Y>` if you want it to finish completion.

That being said, if `completeopt` does not include `noselect`, then you do not need the `<C-N>` in your remap. Adding `<C-N>` would cause vim to move down to the *second* selection in the menu. Either add `noselect` to `completeopt` or remove the `<C-N>` from your remap. Without `noselect`, your remap should be this:

```
inoremap <expr> <c-y> pumvisible() ? "\<c-y>" : "\<c-x>\<c-o>\<c-y>"
```

I will also note that the line:

```
let completeopt=-menu,nomenu
```

is nonsense. `let` can be used to assign options, but they would need to be prefaced with `&` and their values would need to be strings in this case. You also probably meant to use either just `=` or `-=`. When you assign options, just use `set` unless you have a good reason to do it another way.